# Selecting Number of Values of a Child Table for Parent Table

Tags: mysql, sql

On SQL, I have to return all user's name, phone and the number of tickets have, even if it's 0.  I so far have tried using group by but the problem with that is it doesn't show the values of USERS that aren't associated with the ticket table and some extra random names.

User
[image: Users]
Ticket
[image: Ticket]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    U.Name,
    U.Phone,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Users U
LEFT JOIN ticket T
    ON U.USRID = T.USRID
GROUP BY T.USRID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT U.Name, U.Phone, COUNT(T.USRID)
FROM Users U LEFT JOIN
     ticket T
     ON U.USRID = T.USRID
GROUP BY U.Name, U.Phone;
```

Your `GROUP BY` columns should match the `SELECT` columns.